# Did Esther eat at the first feast she made for the king and Haman?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, purim, fast-days, megillat-esther, eating

[Esther 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3305.htm),5:4 says that Esther made the first feast on the third day of the fast.

Earlier ([4:16](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3304.htm#16)), Esther tells Mordechai that she will also fast for three days.

Did she eat at the feast, or was she still fasting?

Comment: By the way, Rashi to [Megilah 16a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=16&format=pdf) (ולתעניתו) says that the "third day" is from when the decree was dispatched, the 13th of Nissan. Hence, though the fast was from 14th-16th (Rashi [15a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=15&format=pdf), "יו"ט ראשון של פסח"), Esther went to the king and made the first feast on the 15th. That means that her 2nd feast was on the 16th, and would _also_ have been during the fast. There are other opinions, like the Midrash Rabba, that hold that the fast was 13th-15th.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Alshich (to 5:5-8)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39973&pgnum=85) says that indeed she didn't eat at the first feast. Among many other things, this explains why the first one is just described as "the party which Esther made" (5:5), while to the second one Achashverosh and Haman came "to drink *with* Queen Esther" (7:1).

Answer (score 5):

The Maharal in his commentary to Megillas Esther says that Esther only fasted for 70 hours (as opposed to 3 full days, 72 hours), and she actually broke her fast before going to Achashverosh to prepare herself for meeting the king.  This is hinted in the verse "גַּם-אֲנִי וְנַעֲרֹתַי, אָצוּם כֵּן; וּבְכֵן אָבוֹא אֶל-הַמֶּלֶךְ" (Esther 4:17) "we will fast כן - "כן is Gematria 70 - Esther was saying that she would fast 70, and with those 70 hours she would come to the King.